# Sass Sequential Animation

Tags: css, animation, sass

https://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/qxPmOR

How do I make this repeat forever, cones appearing on the first pass, then disappearing on the second, and so on? It sort of works on one pass then nothing. It takes an extra pass for them to disappear, too. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

HTML

```
<svg data-rot="0" data-pass="1" id="truck_cones" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 128 128" style="enable-background:new 0 0 128 128;">
<circle id="base" cx="64" cy="64" r="39"/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_30" points="64,20 61,25.2 67,25.2 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_60" points="85.4,25.5 80.2,28.6 85.5,31.5 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_90" points="102.1,41.9 96.1,42 99.1,47.2 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_120" points="108,64 102.8,61 102.8,67 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_150" points="101.9,86.4 98.9,81.2 95.9,86.4 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_180" points="86.2,102 86.2,96 81,99 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_210" points="65,108 67.9,102.7 61.9,102.9 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_240" points="41.6,101.9 46.9,98.9 41.7,95.9 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_270" points="26,86.2 32,86.2 29,81 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_300" points="20,64 25.2,67 25.2,61 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_330" points="25.5,42.6 28.6,47.8 31.5,42.5 "/>
<polygon class="cone" id="cone_360" points="41.9,25.9 42,31.9 47.2,28.9 "/>
<rect id="truck" x="57" y="17" width="14" height="8"/>
</svg>
```

SASS

```
#truck_cones { width: 128px; }
.cone { fill: white; }
#base { fill: gray; }
#truck { fill: blue; transform-origin: 64px 64px; }

@keyframes truck_rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(359deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(719deg); }
}

#truck {
  animation: 5s linear infinite truck_rotate;
}

@keyframes cone_on {
  0% { fill: white; }
  100% { fill: orange; }
}
@keyframes cone_off {
  0% { fill: orange; }
  100% { fill: white; }
}

$cone: 30;
$delay_on: 0s;
$delay_off: 5s;
@for $i from 1 through 13 {
  #cone_#{$cone} {
    animation: .1s $delay_on linear 1 forwards cone_on, .1s $delay_off linear 1 forwards cone_off;
  }
  $cone: $cone + 30;
  $delay_on: $delay_on + 0.2083s;
  $delay_off: $delay_off + 0.2083s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending the duration of the cone animation to match the duration of the truck rotation. Please see the below code and codepen example:

```
#truck_cones { width: 128px; }
.cone { fill: transparent; }
#base { fill: gray; }
#truck { fill: blue; transform-origin: 64px 64px; }

$duration: 2.5s;
$cone_dudation: ($duration * 2);
$steps: 12;
$step_increment: ($cone_dudation / $steps) / 2;

@keyframes truck_rotate {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#truck {
    animation: $duration linear infinite truck_rotate;
}

@keyframes cone_on {
    0% { fill: orange; }
    49.99% { fill: orange; }
    50% { fill: transparent; }
    100% { fill: transparent; }
}
@keyframes cone_off {
    0% { fill: transparent; }
    49.99% { fill: transparent; }
    50% { fill: orange; }
    100% { fill: orange; }
}

$cone: 30;
$delay_on: 0s;
$delay_off: $duration;
@for $i from 1 through $steps {
    #cone_#{$cone} {
        animation: $cone_dudation $delay_on linear infinite cone_on, $cone_dudation $delay_off linear infinite cone_off;
    }
    $cone: $cone + 30;
    $delay_on: $delay_on + $step_increment;
    $delay_off: $delay_off + $step_increment;
}
```

**Working Example:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQwvMj

Comment: That's just about perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, could do with some tweaking to get the first animations running at the right time but at least it's a starting point!

Comment: Yeah, it's funny. The first pass it takes an extra turn but on subsequent cycles, it alternates perfectly...

Comment: I improved it a little more. I realized the different keyframe rules didn't need to be unique, since the only difference is the delay, so I removed them from the loop. I also added step increment and step vars, to make it easier to adjust the overall timing. Still can't figure the initial pass part though...

Comment: Feel free to post your updated codepen and I can have a look

Comment: I've updated my original answer with a new version that solves the first pass issue.